# How to fetch Campaign Group Column Value via LinkedIn Rest API?

Tags: postman, linkedin-api

I have tried fetching the campaign report via postman using this endpoint

[https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=ACCOUNT&dateRange.start.day=24&dateRange.start.month=5&dateRange.start.year=2023&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:507987236&=impressions,clicks](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=ACCOUNT&dateRange.start.day=24&dateRange.start.month=5&dateRange.start.year=2023&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts%5B0%5D=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:507987236&=impressions,clicks)
,

and i do get a response but not the one i am looking for. I have also tried looking at linkedin postman examples at this link:

https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis?tab=workspaces but still having issues or its my lack of API knowledge.

What i want is to get all the columns names and its values that highlighted in yellow in the image below but i help to create an endpoint that would enable me get these columns.

[image: Campaig group page]

Comment: I managed to solve this problem via this link https://mixedanalytics.com/knowledge-base/import-linkedin-reporting-data-google-sheets/#comment-37069